# How to highlight search with / and ? but not * and # vim

Tags: search, highlighting

Is there any way to have vim highlight the search with `/` and `?` but not when putting cursor on a word and pressing `*` or `#`?

`:set hlsearch` and `:set nohlsearch` turn it on and off for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's anything better than switching highlight off just after the search:

```
set hlsearch
nnoremap <silent>* *:noh<CR>
nnoremap <silent># #:noh<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt, this works, but it flashes the highlighting right after pressing * or #. Is there a way that doesn't do this?

Comment: @ThaddaeusMarkle Try `set lazyredraw` if you still don't have it. But there's no guarantee it helps.

Comment: thanks, that works!

Comment: A problem I've been facing with this is that `set lazyredraw` causes lots of lag, especially after vim has been open for a long time.

Comment: @ThaddaeusMarkle I doubt I can help you. Personally, I simply `set incsearch honlsearch` and don't mess with it. You can try to raise an issue on Vim's github page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try this :

1. Open `~/.vimrc` (create it if it didn't exist).
2. Add "set hlsearch" in the file.
3. Save the file.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Unfortunately this doesn't really answer the question, if you re-read it you'll see the OP is already familiar with `hlsearch` but wants to temporarily disable while using the `*` and `#` commands that search for the word under the cursor...

Comment: ahh, i see. that means I misunderstood this topic..